# C++ no matching function for call to `LogBlock<CrazyflieROS::logMotor>`

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ros, error-logging, catkin

I'm trying to modify an [already existing package of ROS](https://github.com/whoenig/crazyflie_ros), adding and removing some stuff in the crazyflie_driver folder. I'm compiling with `catkin_make` and I have *ROS Kinetic 16.04*.
The part that I'm actually modifying of the crazyflie_server C++ script is this:
    private:
      struct logImu {
        float acc_x;
        float acc_y;
        float acc_z;
        float gyro_x;
        float gyro_y;
        float gyro_z;
      } **attribute**((packed));

```
private:
struct logMotor {
        int m1;
        int m2;
        int m3;
        int m4;
    } __attribute__((packed));


    void onImuData(uint32_t time_in_ms, logImu* data) {
    if (m_enable_logging_imu) {
      sensor_msgs::Imu msg;
      if (m_use_ros_time) {
        msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
      } else {
        msg.header.stamp = ros::Time(time_in_ms / 1000.0);
      }
      msg.header.frame_id = m_tf_prefix + "/base_link";
      msg.orientation_covariance[0] = -1;
//new
        msg.orientation.x = cos(data->gyro_z/2)*cos(data->gyro_y/2)*cos(data->gyro_x/2) + sin(data->gyro_z/2)*sin(data->gyro_y/2)*sin(data->gyro_x/2);
    msg.orientation.y = sin(data->gyro_z/2)*cos(data->gyro_y/2)*cos(data->gyro_x/2) - cos(data->gyro_z/2)*sin(data->gyro_y/2)*sin(data->gyro_x/2);
    msg.orientation.z = cos(data->gyro_z/2)*sin(data->gyro_y/2)*cos(data->gyro_x/2) + sin(data->gyro_z/2)*cos(data->gyro_y/2)*sin(data->gyro_x/2);
    msg.orientation.w = cos(data->gyro_z/2)*cos(data->gyro_y/2)*sin(data->gyro_x/2) - sin(data->gyro_z/2)*sin(data->gyro_y/2)*cos(data->gyro_x/2);

//endnew


      // measured in deg/s; need to convert to rad/s
      msg.angular_velocity.x = degToRad(data->gyro_x);
      msg.angular_velocity.y = degToRad(data->gyro_y);
      msg.angular_velocity.z = degToRad(data->gyro_z);

      // measured in mG; need to convert to m/s^2
      msg.linear_acceleration.x = data->acc_x * 9.81;
      msg.linear_acceleration.y = data->acc_y * 9.81;
      msg.linear_acceleration.z = data->acc_z * 9.81;

      m_pubImu.publish(msg);
    }
}

void onMotorData(logMotor* data) {
        std_msgs::Int32MultiArray array;
        array.data.clear();
        array.data.push_back(data->m1);
        array.data.push_back(data->m2);
        array.data.push_back(data->m3);
        array.data.push_back(data->m4);

        m_pubMotors.publish(array);
    }

std::function<void(uint32_t, logImu*)> cb = std::bind(&CrazyflieROS::onImuData, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2);

    logBlockImu.reset(new LogBlock<logImu>(
      &m_cf,{
        {"acc", "x"},
        {"acc", "y"},
        {"acc", "z"},
        {"gyro", "x"},
        {"gyro", "y"},
        {"gyro", "z"},
      }, cb));
    logBlockImu->start(1); // 10ms

 std::function<void(logMotor*)> cbmotor = std::bind(&CrazyflieROS::**onMotorData**, this, std::placeholders::_1);
 logBlockMotor.reset(new LogBlock<logMotor>(
                &m_cf,{
                        {"motor", "m1"},
                        {"motor", "m2"},
                        {"motor", "m3"},
                        {"motor", "m4"},
        }, cbmotor));


        logBlockMotor->start(1); // 10ms


}
```

My problem is that when I try to compile with this part of code:

```
>logBlockMotor.reset(new LogBlock<logMotor>(
                &m_cf,{
                        {"motor", "m1"},
                        {"motor", "m2"},
                        {"motor", "m3"},
                        {"motor", "m4"},
        }, cbmotor));
```

it gives me a no matching function for call to `LogBlock<CrazyflieROS::logMotor>`

```
    /home/bitcraze/catkin_ws/src/crazyflie_ros/crazyflie_driver/src/crazyflie_server.cpp: In member function ‘void CrazyflieROS::run()’:
/home/bitcraze/catkin_ws/src/crazyflie_ros/crazyflie_driver/src/crazyflie_server.cpp:530:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘LogBlock<CrazyflieROS::logMotor>::LogBlock(Crazyflie*, <brace-enclosed initializer list>, std::function<void(unsigned int, CrazyflieROS::logImu*)>&)’
    }, cb));
         ^
In file included from /home/bitcraze/catkin_ws/src/crazyflie_ros/crazyflie_driver/src/crazyflie_server.cpp:50:0:
/home/bitcraze/catkin_ws/src/crazyflie_ros/crazyflie_cpp/include/crazyflie_cpp/Crazyflie.h:462:3: note: candidate: LogBlock<T>::LogBlock(Crazyflie*, std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::function<void(unsigned int, T*)>&) [with T = CrazyflieROS::logMotor]
   LogBlock(
   ^
/home/bitcraze/catkin_ws/src/crazyflie_ros/crazyflie_cpp/include/crazyflie_cpp/Crazyflie.h:462:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘std::function<void(unsigned int, CrazyflieROS::logImu*)>’ to ‘std::function<void(unsigned int, CrazyflieROS::logMotor*)>&’
/home/bitcraze/catkin_ws/src/crazyflie_ros/crazyflie_cpp/include/crazyflie_cpp/Crazyflie.h:459:7: note: candidate: LogBlock<CrazyflieROS::logMotor>::LogBlock(const LogBlock<CrazyflieROS::logMotor>&)
 class LogBlock
       ^
/home/bitcraze/catkin_ws/src/crazyflie_ros/crazyflie_cpp/include/crazyflie_cpp/Crazyflie.h:459:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
crazyflie_ros/crazyflie_driver/CMakeFiles/crazyflie_server.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'crazyflie_ros/crazyflie_driver/CMakeFiles/crazyflie_server.dir/src/crazyflie_server.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [crazyflie_ros/crazyflie_driver/CMakeFiles/crazyflie_server.dir/src/crazyflie_server.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2995: recipe for target 'crazyflie_ros/crazyflie_driver/CMakeFiles/crazyflie_server.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [crazyflie_ros/crazyflie_driver/CMakeFiles/crazyflie_server.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

And this is part of the LogBlock.h file:

```
namespace crazyflie_driver
{
template <class ContainerAllocator>
struct LogBlock_
{
  typedef LogBlock_<ContainerAllocator> Type;

  LogBlock_()
    : topic_name()
    , frequency(0)
    , variables()  {
    }
  LogBlock_(const ContainerAllocator& _alloc)
    : topic_name(_alloc)
    , frequency(0)
    , variables(_alloc)  {
  (void)_alloc;
    }



   typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, typename ContainerAllocator::template rebind<char>::other >  _topic_name_type;
  _topic_name_type topic_name;

   typedef int16_t _frequency_type;
  _frequency_type frequency;

   typedef std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, typename ContainerAllocator::template rebind<char>::other > , typename ContainerAllocator::template rebind<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, typename ContainerAllocator::template rebind<char>::other > >::other >  _variables_type;
  _variables_type variables;





  typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::crazyflie_driver::LogBlock_<ContainerAllocator> > Ptr;
  typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::crazyflie_driver::LogBlock_<ContainerAllocator> const> ConstPtr;

}; // struct LogBlock_
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, also because if I leave in the code the onImuData stuff, it compiles perfectly. As soon as I add that part of the code, the compiler error appears.

Can anyone help me? I tried also to look at the CMake.txt file but it seems that it includes the directories and nothing is wrong:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(crazyflie_driver)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  message_generation
  std_msgs
  tf
  crazyflie_cpp
)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

add_service_files(
  FILES
  AddCrazyflie.srv
  GoTo.srv
  Land.srv
  RemoveCrazyflie.srv
  SetGroupMask.srv
  StartTrajectory.srv
  Stop.srv
  Takeoff.srv
  UpdateParams.srv
  UploadTrajectory.srv
  sendPacket.srv
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  LogBlock.msg
  GenericLogData.msg
  FullState.msg
  TrajectoryPolynomialPiece.msg
  crtpPacket.msg
  Hover.msg
  Position.msg
)

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
   geometry_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
    message_runtime
    std_msgs
    tf
    crazyflie_cpp
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(crazyflie_server
  src/crazyflie_server.cpp
)

add_dependencies(crazyflie_server
  crazyflie_driver_generate_messages_cpp
)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(crazyflie_server
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(crazyflie_add
  src/crazyflie_add.cpp
)

add_dependencies(crazyflie_add
  crazyflie_driver_generate_messages_cpp
)

target_link_libraries(crazyflie_add
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Images of errors are not helpful, please [edit] and paste your *entire* set of error messages *as text*.

Comment: sorry, done! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating

```
std::function<void(logMotor*)> cbmotor = ...
```

and then passing it to a constructor that expects

```
std::function<void(uint32_t, T*)>&
```

(where `T` is presumably `logMotor`). These two types are not compatible. This is what I read in your source.

The error message, on the other hand, says

> no known conversion for argument 3 from 
>   `‘std::function<void(unsigned int, CrazyflieROS::logImu*)>’` to 
>   `‘std::function<void(unsigned int, CrazyflieROS::logMotor*)>&’`

which means you are creating a `logImu` oriented callback and trying to pass it to a `logMotor` oriented parameter. You are probably showing an error message from a file different from the one you have posted as your source.

In any case you need to pass the correct type of callback.

On a somewhat unrelated note:

```
  LogBlock(
    Crazyflie* cf,
    std::list<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > variables,
    std::function<void(uint32_t, T*)>& callback)
```

is a bug in the package you are trying to use. It makes no sense to have a non-const reference `std::function` argument and then immediately copy it to a member variable. This needlessly restricts the constructor to be used only with non-const lvalue arguments. For example, you can do

```
std::function<void(uint32_t, logImu*)> cb = std::bind(...);

new LogBlock<logImu>(..., ..., cb)
```

but you cannot do directly

```
    new LogBlock<logImu>(..., ..., std::bind (...))
```

The constructor should have a const reference parameter, and optionally have an overload with an rvalue reference parameter.

The function also accepts an `std::list` by value, which makes no sense either.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer, so what do you suggest to do? change the costructor in the way that you wrote? I'm not so familiar with c++,  but I have to use it for the end part of my thesis, so can you be very specific on what changes should I do? thank you so much!!!

Comment: You can change the constructor (and send a pull request to the repo owner). If you don't want to change, you can use a *variable* as an argument (as opposed to a general expression).

Comment: Can you do an example if I want to use a variable as an argument? Sorry if I bother you but you seems expert!

Comment: @flavia13 Sorry I didn't look at your code carefully enough. What is said in this answer is correct but doesn't answer your question. I have modified the answer to better address your problem.